# By default, who is allowed to gain root privileges with pkexec?

Tags: root, policykit

I learned today that one can use `pkexec` from the command line, in a manner similar to `sudo`, to execute programs with root privileges.  I am curious how `pkexec` decides who is allowed to do this.

The man page for `pkexec(1)` says

> By default, the org.freedesktop.policykit.exec authorization is required unless an action definition file is present for the program in question.

This is a little challenging to parse for someone unfamiliar with policykit.  But with a little guessing, let's have a look at `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.policy`.  In the `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec` section we see the string `auth_admin`.

Referring to `polkit(8)`, we see:

> `auth_admin`
>
> Authentication by an administrative user is required.

Who exactly is an "administrative user" in this sense?  What tests are done to determine whether a user is "administrative"?  The config files get progressively harder to find and understand.

I am aware this is configurable.  I want to know the default for, say, Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, it's the members of the `sudo` group, and the root user, by virtue of these files in `/etc/polkit/localauthority.conf.d/`:

```
$ tail /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/*
==> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/50-localauthority.conf <==
# Configuration file for the PolicyKit Local Authority.
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, it will be overwritten on update.
#
# See the pklocalauthority(8) man page for more information
# about configuring the Local Authority.
#

[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:0

==> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf <==
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

The first file grants access to UID 0 (`root`), and the second to the groups `sudo` and `admin`. `admin` isn't really used on Ubuntu, but `sudo` is, and it's the group used to grant access to `sudo` as well.